# cordova android launchUrl cannot be resolved to a variable CordovaApp.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I have Installed cordova version 4.1.2 and I have created android app
like this

```
cordova create ll com.example.ll ll
cd ll
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

When i export the app from eclipse, I get this error message.
the problem in the image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/xopSy.png

***When i run the app as android app it crashes.***

Comment: Did you add the library CordovaApp-CordovaLib to current project as library?

Comment: yes i did that i got the CordovaApp-CordovaLib from older versions cause i could not import the liberary with the project cause it is disabled http://s24.postimg.org/gce7824c5/stk1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all existing `CordovaApp-CordovaLib` and `ll` project. Then import both again. Make sure `CordovaApp-CordovaLib` came with `ll` project.

Comment: like i said before, remove all CordovaApp-CordovaLib